# Homotop degree one map $\Sigma_g\to \Sigma_h$ to get a connected transversal inverse image of an embedded circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

Let $f\colon \Sigma_g\to \Sigma_h$ be a degree one smooth map from genus-$g$ surface to genus-$h$ surface for some $g\geq h\geq0$, crushing handle gives raise such kind of map. Let $C$ be a smoothly embedded simple closed curve in $\Sigma_h$ representing a non-trivial element of $\pi_1(\Sigma_h)$.

Now, we can homotop $f$ to make it transverse with $C$, so after homotopy  $f^{-1}(C)$ is either empty or one dimensional embedded compact submanifold, **possibly disconnected**, of $\Sigma_g$. And for the latter case, by Stack of Record theorem $f\big| f^{-1}(C) \to C$ is a finite-fold covering.

> Can we homotop futher so that $f^{-1}(C)$ is either empty or a single
> circle embedded in $\Sigma_g$?

The case $g=h$ is clear to me, as any degree-one self-map is homotopic to a homeomorphism, hence homotopic to a diffeomorphism. So, one needs to consider $g>h$. Just as a note every map from lower genus to higher genus has degree zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course $f^{-1}(C)$ will never be empty: then $f$ is not surjective and so does not have degree 1. But you can make $f$ restrict to a homeomorphism on $f^{-1}(C)$.

Every degree-1 map $g: \Sigma_g \to \Sigma_h$ is homotopic to a map $f$ which collapses a subsurface $S \subset \Sigma_g$ to a point $f(S) \in \Sigma_h$ but is otherwise an oriented homeomorphism $f: \Sigma_g \setminus S \to \Sigma_h \setminus f(S)$. This follows from a result of [Edmonds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971246?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Now simply choose a representative for $C$ which does not include the single point $f(S)$.